# .htaccess route with file check not working with querystring

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm certainly no expert with .htaccess files, so bear with me..

I have a nice simple rule:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/landing-pages/$1.aspx -f
RewriteRule ^/(.[^/]*)/?$ /landing-pages/$1.aspx [NC,L,QSA]
```

So if I go to a page:

http://myexampledomain.com/my-landing/page/

It is rewritten correctly to:

http://myexampledomain.com/landing-pages/my-landing-page.aspx

This works fine, until the original URL has a querystring on it:

http://myexampledomain.com/my-landing/page/?foo=bar

At this point, the rewrite condition isn't met (I assume the querystring is part of $1 ?) and so I get a page not found.

I have tried changing my condition to:

```
RewriteCond /landing-pages/%{REQUEST_URI}.aspx -f
```

However, I suspect that %{REQUEST_URI} contains both leading and trailing slashes so that does not work either.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I get the condition to ignore the querystring, but still append the querystring in the rule?

Any help appreciated.

p.s. I know routing is available in .net 3.5+ but currently that is not an option, we are already using .htaccess via Helicon's asapi_rewrite module.

Thanks

Edit:

I have since added another condition and rule to try and narrow down where the problem is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} foo=bar 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/?$ /landing-pages/$1.aspx? [NC,L,QSA]
```

So now this is set to specifically Rewrite if the query string foo=bar exists. Using this I can see that the requested URL after the Rewrite is:

http://myexampledomain.com/landing-pages/my-landing-page/?foo=bar.aspx?foo=bar

It's certainly not how I expected it to behave..

Comment: _“I assume the querystring is part of $1 ?”_ – no, it’s not; RewriteRule only matches on the path component of the URL, not the query string. And before we discuss this any further, please edit your posting and format your code in a more readable way.

Comment: @CBroe Apologies, should read a bit better now. I confess to being a little confused as to why the query string should affect my condition then if it's effectively being ignored in my condition? Especially as it appears to work fine if there is no query string. Certainly my initial thoughts were that the query string is a separate entity and so should just be appended to my RewriteRule..

Comment: OK, I've done an edit to include another RewriteCond which appears to go against how I thought it should work, but my understanding of it is minimal.